# When using the ExecutorService.invokeAll is there a way of getting all responses even if an exception occurred

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

In java I want to run multiple threads and get the response back from all of them.

The issue I have is if one of the threads throws an exception when I do the String temp = r.get() it drops into the catch and doesn't give me the response from the remaining threads.

Is there a way of processing all the responses regardless of whether the individual thread threw an exception?

My test code is

```
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    List<CallTest> callList = new ArrayList<>();

    callList.add(new CallTest(1));
    callList.add(new CallTest(2));
    callList.add(new CallTest(3));
    callList.add(new CallTest(4));


    try {
        List<Future<String>> returns = es.invokeAll(callList);
        for (Future<String> r : returns) {
            String temp = r.get();
            System.out.println("returned " + temp);

        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("Interrupted Exception catch");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        System.out.println("Execution Exception catch");
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Comment: Put the try-catch around the individual `r.get()` instead of the whole loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Catch exceptions inside the loop

```
for (Future<String> r : returns) {
    try {
        String temp = r.get();
        System.out.println("returned " + temp);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("Interrupted Exception catch");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        System.out.println("Execution Exception catch");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, as a relative newcomer to Java (from Cobol of all things) where to put the try/catch is not always obvious

Answer (score 2):

Other solution:

Override `afterExecute` method in [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)

```
protected void afterExecute(Runnable r,
                Throwable t)
```

> Method invoked upon completion of execution of the given Runnable. This method is invoked by the thread that executed the task. If non-null, the Throwable is the uncaught RuntimeException or Error that caused execution to terminate abruptly.

Sample code from oracle documentation link:

```
class ExtendedExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {
   // ...
   protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
     super.afterExecute(r, t);
     if (t == null && r instanceof Future<?>) {
       try {
         Object result = ((Future<?>) r).get();
       } catch (CancellationException ce) {
           t = ce;
       } catch (ExecutionException ee) {
           t = ee.getCause();
       } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
           Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); // ignore/reset
       }
     }
     if (t != null)
       System.out.println(t);
   }
 }
```